# Is there any kind of udev equivalent on Windows?

Tags: windows, udev

I'm looking for a way to ensure that a USB device plugged into a Windows 7 machine will be mounted in a reliable, repeatable way.

I don't have that much Windows experience, but I wondered if there was a way to make the equivalent of a udev rule in Linux to match certain parameters to identify the device and then mount it on a specific COM port.

Any advice would be gratefully received.

Comment: Does the accepted answer really answer your question? Could you give more detail so we can learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sarcastic answer:

> I've looked for `C:\Windows\etc\udev.d` but there's no such directory
> ;)

Less sarcastic answer:

As far as I know, the only way to configure devices in windows is via the device management UI which can be started with `mmc devmgmt.msc`

This is obviously not even similar or even close to udev, there is no possibility to do this without the GUI.

[image]

Comment: That is not similar or even close to udev, there is no possibility to do this without GUI.